# Python Time Series - Implementing Calendar Week to plot and forecast

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have the following table for the whole year 2020:

[image]

and I would like to fit this into a dataframe time series to firstly plot and then forecast for the year 2021 using ML.

My problem is implementing the Calender weeks by means of conversion. Or maybe it doesn't have to be converted and I'm thinking too complicated.

Normally, I would use

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df[['year', 'month', 'day']])
```

but how do I do this using calender weeks?

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
df_2020 = pd.DataFrame(data={'date':pd.date_range(datetime(2020,1,1), datetime(2020, 12, 31), freq='W')})
df_2020['week'] = df_2020['date'].dt.isocalendar().week
your_df = your_df.merge(df_2020, how='left', left_on='Calendar Week', right_on='week')
```

Comment: yes, this last version basically worked for me..Followed by:  your_df .index=pd.to_datetime(your_df ['date']) thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

Calendar weeks can be parsed with `pd.to_datetime` using `%U` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes).

But with `pd.to_datetime` you will also need to provide an information about the day of week (parsed with `%w`), otherwise parsing will fail.

The code could look like:

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO


data = """Year,Calendar Week,Month,Amount
2020,1,12,129.984
2020,2,1,263.136
2020,3,1,592.896
2020,4,1,470.016
2020,5,1,429.888
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep=",")

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(
    df[['Year', 'Calendar Week']].astype(str).apply(' '.join, 1)  # create temp column with year and week info
    + ' 0',  # add day info
    format='%Y %U %w'
)

print(df)

   Year  Calendar Week  Month   Amount       date
0  2020              1     12  129.984 2020-01-05
1  2020              2      1  263.136 2020-01-12
2  2020              3      1  592.896 2020-01-19
3  2020              4      1  470.016 2020-01-26
4  2020              5      1  429.888 2020-02-02
```